# ViewPager and TabLayout

Tags: android

this is my code:

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    EventsPagerAdapter eventsPagerAdapter = new EventsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this ,2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(eventsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(eventsPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

i want to know if it is possible to set the ViewPager to position 1 and the TabLayout to position 0, and if it is possible i want to know how to do that.

this is the image when i start the app.
the right tab position is 1.
i want the app to start with the right tab and not the left tab.
also in the start of the app, the viewpager position is set to 0, so i can only scroll left to right, but the problem is i want is to start from 1 and than scroll right to left.
[image]

[image]

ty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why would you want that? This sounds like bad UX.

You use the method `setupWithViewPager` which does the following according to the documentation:

> The one-stop shop for setting up this TabLayout with a ViewPager.
>
> This method will:
>
> - Add a ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener that will forward events to this TabLayout.
> - Populate the TabLayout's tabs from the ViewPager's PagerAdapter.
> - Set our TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener which will forward selected events to the ViewPager

This means that all changes are forwared to your `ViewPager` so changing the position in your `TabLayout` will change the person in `ViewPager`.

You could however setup all yourself and manage the forwarding of scrolls.

Comment: i want to do this because my language is RIGHT TO LEFT, and it causes me problems with the setup of tablayout with viewpager.
i can add a picture if it is neccessery.

Comment: Please do so, It would help me (or other users) to get what the problems is.